# Send Email from Laravel Commands and Scheduler

Tags: email, laravel-5, command, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to make a scheduled task using commands but does not work MailFacade to send emails.

The Command Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;


use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ToDoUserAlert extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'toDoAlert';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send ToDo user alerts by email';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::raw(date('Y-m-d').' '.date('H:i'), function ($message) {
            $message->to('sairam.santana@gmail.com');
            $message->subject('Reminder Notification');
        });
    }
}
```

Kerner:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\ToDoUserAlert::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('toDoAlert')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to help you, I've some questions:
1. Did you enter this cron `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to your server? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#introduction for more info.

2. Are you able to send email from other locations in your app?